# Problem with building an ANN for regression Problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am having a problem with accuracy and loss while building an ANN for predicting the sales of video games. The loss is very high as 4.3 and accuracy is stuck at 0. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

dataset = pd.read_csv('Train.csv')
#dropping one outlier
dataset = dataset.drop(dataset[(dataset['SalesInMillions']>60)].index)


X = dataset.iloc[:,3:8]
Y = dataset['SalesInMillions'].values

dataset.drop('SalesInMillions', axis=1, inplace=True)

#getting dummy variables for categorical values - Rating, Category
print(dataset.shape) #pre-dummies shape
dataset = pd.get_dummies(data=dataset, columns=['CATEGORY', 'RATING'])
print(dataset.shape) #post-dummies shape
dataset.head() #Check to verify that dummies are ok

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
dataset['le_publisher'] = le.fit_transform(dataset['PUBLISHER'])
dataset.head()

X = dataset.iloc[:,4:]

"""#Model Building"""

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    Dense(32, input_shape=X_train[0].shape, activation='relu'),
                                    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                                    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                                    Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

r = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10)
```

Result:

```
>Epoch 1/10
74/74 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 5.3924 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.1689 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00  
>Epoch 2/10
74/74 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4.7189 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.1634 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00  
>Epoch 3/10
74/74 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4.6166 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.0874 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00  
>Epoch 4/10
74/74 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.5860 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.0585 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00  
>Epoch 5/10
74/74 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.5070 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.1005 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: Since, you're expecting a regression value then, set final layer activation to "linear"

Comment: It does matter if I leave out the activation function for regression as the default is None and it does not change the value. Still I tried 'linear', did not help.

Answer (score 1):

`accuracy` is not a valid metric for a regression problem, because it looks for a perfect match between actual value and prediction. If your samples look like this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[9.522715  , 6.7740774 , 7.953182  ],
        [7.5578175 , 4.759556  , 6.3101482 ],
        [1.8602037 , 1.1430776 , 3.3622181 ]],
       [[7.2333503 , 2.1919966 , 8.573376  ],
        [8.239203  , 5.9541273 , 0.02962708],
        [2.4725473 , 5.0607405 , 3.6158872 ]],
       [[0.44838428, 9.721661  , 8.283884  ],
        [4.1458406 , 6.0166597 , 3.3958685 ],
        [5.731027  , 2.3625553 , 6.7478456 ]]], dtype=float32)>
```

The odds of a perfect match are one in 100,000,000 per value. Continuous loss functions or metrics are `mae`, `mse`, `mape`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand this but this still does not solve why the loss is not decreasing. I changed loss to 'mae' and the best loss I get is 1.18.

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem. A neural net doesn't always fit to perfection. If you add more layers and increase the numbers of neurons, the loss might decrease, but maybe it will overfit.